# Unique words of even letters in a data file - Java

Tags: java

I am trying to find the total number of unique words contained within all of the Latin names in a data file that have an even number of letters. This is the code I so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int evenWord = 0;
    evenWord += countEvenWord(latinName);
    System.out.print("Total number of unique even words in Latin names = ");
    System.out.println(evenWord);
}

public static int countEvenWord(String name) {    
    int numberEven = 0;
    if(name.length() % 2 == 0) {
        String[] person = name.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
        for(String token: sharks) {
            numberEven += token.length();
        }
    }
    return numberEven;
}
```

output:

```
Total number of unique even words in Latin names = 297
```

The code does find the total number of even letters within all the latin names, but I want to find the total number of unique words contained in the data file.

The data file:

```
David Lee:Cephaloscyllium ventriosum
Max Steel:Galeocerdo cuvier
Jimmy Park:Sphyrna mokarren
...
```

Comment: here you are summing up the lengths of the words having an even number of letters, not the words count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Set<String>` and store the names in that. This will preserve uniqueness.

```
public static int countEvenWord(String name) { 
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

    int numberEven = 0;
    if(name.length() % 2 == 0) {
        set.add(name);
        }
    }
    return set.size();
}
```

**N.B:** I haven't written name retrieval logic.

***EDIT***

```
String name = "David Lee:Cephaloscyllium ventriosum";
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

            String[] sharks = name.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
            for(String token: sharks) {
                if(token.length()%2==0)
                    set.add(token);
            }
        return set.size();
```

Comment: What about numberEven? It hasn't been used.

Answer (score 0):

Your **countUniqueWords** method will be like

```
public static int countUniqueWords(String latinName) {    
            int numberEven = 0;
            String[] words=latinName.split(" ");
            Set<String> uniqueWords=new HashSet();
            for(String word:words) {
                if(word.length()%2==0) {
                    uniqueWords.add(word);
                }
            }
            return uniqueWords.size();
        }
```

Comment: you might want to change `word.length()%2==1`